# R dotplot bind color to group

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to create a `dotplot` where I want the dots to be colored by group. But I can't bind a specific color to a specific group. My grouping variable is always `c(1,2,3)` where 1=black, 2=red and 3=green. But in cases where there are no group=2, `dotplot` handles the grouping variable as `c(1,2)` not `c(1,3)`.

Consider the following example:

```
test <- data.frame(
    year = c(rep(2021, 3), rep(2022, 3), rep(2023, 3)),
    category = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3),
    value = c(1.23, 2.34, 1.54, 6.23, 8.67, 6.67, 4.78, 3.56, 6.90),
    grp = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
)

lattice::dotplot(factor(year) ~ value | category,
    data = test,
    group = grp,
    col = c("#000000", "#ff0000", "#00ff00"),
    pch = 16,
    cex = 2,
    layout = c(1, 3)
)
```

[image: Correct colors]

The reference is always the current year, so that dot is black for all categories (grp=1). All dots lower than the reference value is red and green when higher.

In the example below the grouping variable only contains `c(1,3)` and all dot values are higher than the reference values, and I want the dots to be green.

```
test <- data.frame(
    year = c(rep(2021, 3), rep(2022, 3), rep(2023, 3)),
    category = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3),
    value = c(3.23, 6.34, 4.54, 4.23, 4.67, 6.67, 2.78, 3.01, 4.00),
    grp = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1)
)

lattice::dotplot(factor(year) ~ value | category,
    data = test,
    group = grp,
    col = c("#000000", "#ff0000", "#00ff00"),
    pch = 16,
    cex = 2,
    layout = c(1, 3)
)
```

[image]

But `dotplot` seems to grab the colors in order of appearance. Is there a way to bind group values to specific colors?